# Error: missing From- Clause entry for Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't figure this out in `postgresql`:

```
SELECT Week1.Material, Week1.VALa, Week1.MVGavgprice, concat(Week1.Material, Week1.VALa)

FROM "Week1"
```

**ERROR:**

> missing FROM-clause entry for table "week1"
>   LINE 1: SELECT Week1.Material, Week1.VALa, Week1.MVGavgprice, concat...
>                  ^
>   SQL state: 42P01
>   Character: 8

Comment: Get rid of quotes around week1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive)

Comment: @DanielMarcus if the table was created with the sensitivity specified he'll need to _add_ quotes around "Week1" in the `SELECT` list instead.

Comment: hmm ok thanks @dmfay

Comment: this didnt work: SELECT Week1.Material
FROM public.Week1;

Comment: you need to select from Week1 not public.week1

Comment: SELECT * FROM Public."Week1" works.

Comment: But as soon as I do: Select Week1.Material FROM Public."Week1" FAIL

Comment: ERROR:  relation "sap.week1" does not exist
LINE 2: FROM SAP.Week1;

Comment: I change DB name to SAP

Comment: Got it. For some reason, it needs quotes around "Week1"."Material" etc...

Comment: Why would Postgre ask that?